# Confluence - search/filter task lists

Tags: confluence

We want to switch **from OneNote to Confluence for task tracking** because we start with Jira as well.

What is really great in OnteNote for tasks tracking is the live search. Just type in any word that you can remember about the task and you're gonna find it.

Is there a way to **search/filter task lists** in Confluence?

- Can I set labels to tables/tasks (not only to pages)? Can I set tags/hashtags?
- Can I customize the search so that I get directed to the exact line on a page and not just to the page?
- Or filter a table so that for example I have only one specific assigned person left (in case the person doesn't have a Confluence account and is just written in a colmn)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks, I try to edit and opimize my question